# vb6 and vsflexgrid - how to add vsflex8U (vsflexgrid 8 unicode) as a form control programatically

Tags: unicode, vb6, vsflexgrid

im using vb6 and does anybody know how to add vsflex8U(known as vsflex8 unicode ) programatically , i have search and tried several solutions and i can add vsflex programatically but not in unicode please help me thanks have a good day !

here is my sample code

```
Dim WithEvents dynamicVSFlexGrid As VBControlExtender

Dim StrLicenseKey As String
StrLicenseKey = Licenses.Add("VSFlexGrid8.VSFlexGridADO", "O0OOEC742")
Set dynamicVSFlexGrid = Form1.Controls.Add("VSFlexGrid8.VSFlexGridADO", "VSFlexGrid81")
```

Comment: You should add more details of what you have tried and what went wrong.

Comment: VB6 is ANSI - not UNICODE, Try to search UNICODE library for VB6 or COM